# CSS Dynamic width on element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an horizontal layout, though the UL element keeps clipping and putting it back on new line.

Like this:

[image]

What I want is that everything is on a single line that without having to set the width manually.

The site can be seen here: http://prv.sampettersson.com

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Pietu1998 setting the width manually (not ideal), setting the width to 100%, setting the width to auto, setting html, body to 100% (didn't do anything), and some more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` on the parent element

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the better solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to do that:

**CSS**

```
ul{
list-style: none;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 20000px;
}
```

Comment: Somewhat what i did to begin with. I can't do that as their are multiple element containing different amounts of photos. What I need is to have the element set to 100% or something like that (which is what doesn't work)